# merge timeseries with merge_asof and keep the longest time horizon (outer join)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, time-series

I got mutltiple dataframes with different lengths and dates as index, which I want to merge into only one dataframe using `merge_asof` `'backward'` logic.

I naturally do this like the following:
1. put all dataframes into a list.
2. merge two by two with merge_asof

```
data_list = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4, df_5, df_6]
data_mrg = data_list[0]
for data_mrg_new in data_list[1:]:
    data_mrg = pd.merge_asof(data_mrg, data_mrg_new, left_index=True, right_index=True, direction='backward')
```

The only issue I have here is that `data_list[0]` (=`df_1`) determines the time horizon. So if `df_1` contains data starting from 2017 and df_4 contains data starting from 2005, only the 2017-2020 data will be matched and `data_mrg` will have 2017-2020 data.

Is there an easy way to always keep the longest timeseries as the index and insert nan if the other dataframes have a shorter time period?

of course sorting the data list would do the job but that would interfere with the code that follows, so I was looking for another way to do it. Is there a parameter for `merge_asof` that can do that?